# Detecting if two variables have the same value

Tags: if-statement, variables, var

I am new to coding, so I've been creating simple programs. I'm currently trying to make a guess the number program. I'm currently having issues trying to make the program tell you whether you won or lost by detecting whether the number entered by the user is equal to the number that was generated. This is my code, and I am currently getting a syntax error on line 10, which I don't understand. Please help me!

```
import time
from time import sleep
import random
var1 = "Hello"
print(var1)
time.sleep(1)
print("I'm going to pick a number now!")
time.sleep(2)
value = (random.randint(1, 9)
print("Okay, now it's your turn!")
usernumber = input("""Pick a number, 1-9:
""")
time.sleep(1)
var2 = "I picked..."
print(var2)
time.sleep(1)
print(value)
if var3 == usernumber
    print("You win!")
if var3 != usernumber
    print("You lose. :(")
```

Comment: You're missing a close parenthesis, which your IDE should have alerted you to.

Comment: Where am I missing a close parenthesis?

Answer (score 0):

```
value = (random.randint(1, 9)
```

Note the missing parenthesis.
It should be

```
value = (random.randint(1, 9))
```

Comment: Okay, thank you so much! I can't believe I didn't notice that. Now it works!

Comment: No problem, actually you can remove the first parenthesis and the last one from that line, that's the better option. Welcome to the world of coding, there's a lot to learn! But it's a lot of fun